# Replace NOT IN with LEFT JOIN in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wrote two queries which are working fine, but they are really really slow:

```
SELECT director
FROM movies
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT movie_id FROM stars_in_movies WHERER star_id = %s);

SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM stars
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT star_id
                 FROM stars_in_movies
                 WHERE movie_id IN(SELECT movie_id
                                   FROM stars_in_movies
                                   WHERE star_id = %s))
```

I tried to replace `NOT IN` with `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` but nothing I have tried worked so far.

Following is schema for the tables:

**movies**:

```
 - id (primary key),
 - title (title of the movie), 
 - year (year of release)
 - director (director of the movie)
```

**stars**:

```
 - id (primary key)
 - first_name
 - last_name
```

**stars_in_movies**:

```
 - movie_id, 
 - star_id (movie_id and star_id both are foreign keys here)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For any large movie database, the query will fetch a lot of results and run slowly no matter how you write it. You are looking to separate a needle in a haystack from the haystack. All the directors of movies in the database except the directors who have only directed movies starring a particular actor, and not directed any other movie. It may not be what you actually intend to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.director 
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN stars_in_movies sm ON m.id = sm.movie_id
WHERE sm.movie_id IS NULL 
AND sm.star_id = %s
```

the second query

```
  SELECT first_name, last_name
  FROM stars s
  LEFT JOIN stars_in_movies sm
  ON sm.star_id = s.id
  WHERE sm.star_id IS NULL
  AND sm.star_id = %s
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay but first query still processing really slow

Comment: then its a question on indexes, rather you have many indexes so you must abort them and let only what you need.or you need to create one if you dont have.

Comment: its much simplified the query now , as i said now its indexes.

Comment: Oh okay. That actually make sense. Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.director
from movies t1 left outer join stars_in_movies t2 on t1.id = t2.movie_id
where t2.movie_id is null;

select t1.first_name, t1.last_name
from stars t1 left outer join stars_in_movies t2 on t1.id = t2.star_id
where t2.star_id is null;
```

here is an **[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac0e3/7)**

Answer (score 1):

I know iam late to the party but this might help someone -

**Query with NOT IN (Slow)**

```
Select I.InquiryId,I.InquirySubject,I.CreateDt,I.SendTo,I.[From],U.Email as SendBy
From Inquiries I  
Inner Join Users U  
ON I.[From] = U.UserID  
Where I.InquiryId Not In (Select InquiryId from InquiryReply)  
And I.InquiryStatusId  <> 5  
And DATEDIFF(day, I.CreateDt, getdate()) >=10
```

**Query with Left Join (Faster)**

```
 Select I.InquiryId,I.InquirySubject,I.CreateDt,I.SendTo,I.[From],U.Email as SendBy  
  From Inquiries I  
  Left Outer Join InquiryReply IR
  On I.InquiryId = IR.InquiryId
  Inner Join Users U
  ON I.[From] = U.UserID
  Where IR.InquiryId Is NULL
  And I.InquiryStatusId  <> 5  
  And DATEDIFF(day, I.CreateDt, getdate()) >=10
```