# How to replace NOT IN with JOIN in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql

**How to write the query using joins for the specific query which i mentioned?** It will be really great if someone can help me out!!! I am trying out for many days but i am not getting the expected results with JOINS, I have tried Left , Right Join but still i am not getting the proper results,

Without Joins:

```
select distinct SchoolId, utc_timestamp
from schools 
where schoolId not in ( select schoolId
                        from school_grades
                        where gradeId like '2abaf802-70c5-4096-a830-7e8873ab3772')
  and graphCode in ('Florida');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite MySQL queries - Replace "NOT IN" with left join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434517/rewrite-mysql-queries-replace-not-in-with-left-join)

Comment: Unless using a case sensitive COLLATION, `like '2abaf802-70c5-4096-a830-7e8873ab3772'` is the same as `= '2abaf802-70c5-4096-a830-7e8873ab3772'`

Answer (score 1):

**You should try this one.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        s.SchoolId ,
        utc_timestamp
FROM    schools s
        INNER JOIN school_grades ON s.schoolId != schoolId
                                    AND gradeId LIKE '2abaf802-70c5-4096-a830-7e8873ab3772'
                                    AND s.graphCode IN ( 'Florida' ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be appropriate to use `EXISTS` in this case:

```
select distinct s.SchoolId, utc_timestamp
from schools s
where NOT EXISTS (select  *
                        from school_grades
                        where gradeId like '2abaf802-70c5-4096-a830-7e8873ab3772' AND 
                              schoolId = s.schoolId)
  and s.graphCode in ('Florida');
```

Depends on why you want you to replace `IN` with `JOIN`.

Comment: Hi Bulat, Thanks for the reply, its just a challenge in queries in my team, we need to use JOINS rather than NOT IN. Please see the below queries which is working fine rite now,

Comment: select distinct s.SchoolId , utc_timestamp
from schools s
left join school_grades sg on s.schoolId = sg.schoolId
                          and sg.gradeId like '2abaf802-70c5-4096-a830-7e8873ab3772'
where sg.schoolId is null
and s.graphCode in ('Florida');

Comment: Np, this may be useful for someone else

Comment: @mariapradeep A challenge for who exactly? You? So why ask us?

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I have applied the same query but little different. So i asked help in the forum and thanks for all the replies.