# How to write the query without using sub query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query and it works perfectly but I wanted to improve it and write it without sub-query. Is this possible? Although I have tried a lot, I am not able to get correct results.

```
SELECT * FROM store_product
    WHERE product_id NOT IN (
                SELECT entity_id
                FROM import_pack_file_element
                    WHERE entity_id IS NOT NULL
                       AND import_pack_file_id IN (135)
                       AND status = 'DONE') AND store_id = 65
```

Comment: Writing this query without a subquery would be a disimprovement, rather than an improvement.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, aggre with it. Using subquery is more efficient than just do it with one line of query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LEFT JOIN and IS NULL condition

```
SELECT store_product.* 
FROM store_product 
LEFT JOIN import_pack_file_element ON store_product.product_id = import_pack_file_element.entity_id 
    AND import_pack_file_element.import_pack_file_id IN (135)
    AND import_pack_file_element.status = 'DONE'
WHERE  
   import_pack_file_element.entity_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already tried this. It returns me store_products that are in import_pack_file_element but I want to get store_products that are not in import_pack_file_element. See my query that why I'm using not in.

Comment: @Akmal this query return products which not exists in import_pack_file_element table, because used IS NULL condition in LEFT JOIN

Comment: Yes, I am sorry you're right. I should write I want to get store_products are not in import_pack_file_element.import_pack_file_id=135

Comment: @Akmal: This query is a perfect re-write of your original query. It does exactly the same thing, namely return all products that have no 135/DONE record in import_pack_file_element.

Comment: This should be `SELECT store_product.*`. I made the same mistake in my answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are right. Thanks! I fixed it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes at some case the query is correct. Previously I had the same query but the problem here `import_pack_file_element.entity_id IS NULL` It won't take the store_products that are in import_pack_file_element but has different import_pack_file_id.

Comment: @Akmal. It does. It does the same as your original query. Have you even tried it or are you guessing? My query doesn't even look whether an `import_pack_file_element` with another ID exists or not. Same as yours.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, You are absolutely right. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite a `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` query to an anti join. I don't see any reason, however, why you'd want to do that. Anti joins are usually used on DBMS that have problems with the straight-forward `[NOT] IN` / `[NOT] EXISTS`, which should not be the case with MySQL. Anti joins are a means to defend against a DBMS weakness and come at the price of loss of readability.

```
SELECT sp.*
FROM store_product sp
LEFT JOIN import_pack_file_element ipfe
  ON ipfe.entity_id = sp.product_id
  AND ipfe.import_pack_file_id = 135
  AND ipfe.status = 'DONE'
WHERE ipfe.entity_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This most likely won't outperform an `EXISTS` query.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen: But it does answer the question how to write the query without a subquery, which `NOT EXISTS` does not.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, it shows different result then my sub-query.

Comment: @Akmal: Sorry, it must be `sp.*`, not `*` that I select of course. I've updated my answer. Apart from this, the result must equal yours (but the order may differ, because we have specified no `ORDER BY`) or you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thank you so much. Your answer correct too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM store_product sp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM import_pack_file_element i
                  WHERE i.entity_id = sp.product_id AND 
                        import_pack_file_id = 135 AND status = 'DONE');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! but one question. Does NOT EXISTS have some advantage over NOT IN?

Comment: @Akmal `EXISTS` is probably the best way to write your query, and should outperform a join.  `NOT IN` might be optimized to an `EXISTS` clause by MySQL.

Comment: This is still a subquery of course :-) @Akmal: MySQL was notorious for having problems with `IN` / `NOT IN`. I don't know, whether this is still the case. Of course the two queries do exactly the same thing, so MySQL should come up with the same execution plan for both. But maybe it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen, It looks like there is not way without subquery in this case.

Comment: Check Thorsten's answer.  There is a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this(but better use Subquery instead):

```
SELECT [table alias].*
FROM store_product [table alias]
LEFT JOIN import_pack_file_element [table alias] on [table alias].[key] = [table alias].[key]
WHERE [table alias].entity_id IS NOT NULL AND [table alias].import_pack_file_id IN(135) AND [table alias].status = 'DONE'
```

You can modify `LEFT JOIN` part and `WHERE` part as your needs.

also this : [key] to your table key, [table alias] to your table alias.

and also this, u can replace IN(135) and use equals sign `=`, IN is use for more than one element that u need to compare or validate.

and here the reference :

[LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434517/replace-not-in-with-left-join-in-sql-statement)

Comment: This returns *all* products, even alaong with all their import_pack_file_element. This is because you forgot the WHERE clause to only keep outer-joined rows and make this an anti join thus.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the full knowledge about your table design but this might work:

```
SELECT * FROM store_product x LEFT OUTER JOIN import_pack_file_element y
                              ON x.product_id = y.entity_id
 WHERE x.product_id IS NULL
   AND import_pack_file_id = 135 
   AND status = 'DONE'
```

Comment: I don't see any table design that would make this work actually. What gives you the idea to only select store_product rows with product_id NULL for instance? I suggest you delete this answer. You shouldn't use obfuscating table aliases by the way. Use something mnemonic, so one doesn't have to look up all the time wich table was x and which was y.